# Array of Heroes won't show up on browser, using Angular 4 and ngrx 4

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm new to Angular 4 and ngrx 4. I am trying to convert Angular 2 Tour of Heroes into Angular 4 using ngrx 4 version. As of now I have the app up and running with the dashboard and heroes pages showing. Problem is that none of my heroes are showing up and no errors are showing up on chrome's dev tools. I'm not sure what is holding this up. Any tips or guidance would be appreciated.

```
hero.actions.ts

import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

import { Hero } from './../models/hero';


export const GET_HEROES = '[Hero] Get Heroes';
export const GET_HEROES_SUCCESS = '[Hero] Get Heroes Success';
export const GET_HEROES_FAIL = '[Hero] Get Heroes Fail'
export const GET_HERO = '[Hero] Get Hero';
export const GET_HERO_SUCCESS = '[Hero] Get Hero Success';
export const GET_HERO_FAIL = '[Hero] Get Hero Fail';
export const CREATE_HERO = '[Hero] Create Hero';
export const CREATE_HERO_SUCCESS = '[Hero] Create Hero Success';
export const CREATE_HERO_FAIL = '[Hero] Create Hero Fail';
export const DELETE_HERO = '[Hero] Delete Hero';
export const DELETE_HERO_SUCCESS = '[Hero] Delete Hero Success';
export const DELETE_HERO_FAIL = '[Hero] Delete Hero Fail';
export const UPDATE_HERO = '[Hero] Update Hero';
export const UPDATE_HERO_SUCCESS = '[Hero] Update Hero Success';
export const UPDATE_HERO_FAIL = '[Hero] Update Heo Fail';





export class GetHeroesAction implements Action {
            readonly type = GET_HEROES;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
 export class GetHeroesSuccessAction implements Action {
            readonly type = GET_HEROES_SUCCESS;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
 export class GetHeroesFailAction implements Action {
            readonly type = GET_HEROES_FAIL;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class GetHeroAction implements Action {
            readonly type = GET_HERO;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class GetHeroSuccessAction implements Action {
            readonly type = GET_HERO_SUCCESS;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class GetHeroFailAction implements Action {
            readonly type = GET_HEROES_FAIL
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class CreateHeroAction implements Action {
            readonly type = CREATE_HERO;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class CreateHeroSuccessAction implements Action {
            readonly type = CREATE_HERO_SUCCESS;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
 export class CreateHeroFailAction implements Action {
            readonly type = CREATE_HERO_FAIL;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class DeleteHeroAction implements Action {
            readonly type = DELETE_HERO;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class DeleteHeroSuccessAction implements Action {
            readonly type = DELETE_HERO_SUCCESS;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class DeleteHeroFailAction implements Action {
            readonly type = DELETE_HERO_FAIL;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}

export class UpdateHeroAction implements Action {
            readonly type = UPDATE_HERO;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class UpdateHeroSuccessAction implements Action {
            readonly type = UPDATE_HERO_SUCCESS;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}
export class UpdateHeroFailAction implements Action {
            readonly type = UPDATE_HERO_FAIL;
            constructor(public payload: Hero) {}
}

export type HeroActions
= GetHeroesAction
| GetHeroesSuccessAction
| GetHeroesFailAction
| GetHeroAction
| GetHeroSuccessAction
| GetHeroFailAction
| CreateHeroAction
| CreateHeroSuccessAction
| CreateHeroFailAction
| DeleteHeroAction
| DeleteHeroSuccessAction
| DeleteHeroFailAction
| UpdateHeroAction
| UpdateHeroSuccessAction
| UpdateHeroFailAction;



    hero.effect.ts

    import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Effect, Actions, toPayload } from '@ngrx/effects';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';

    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
    import { empty } from 'rxjs/observable/empty';

    // import other files
    import { AppState } from './../reducers';
    import { Hero } from './../models/hero';
    import * as heroes from './../actions/hero.action';
    import { HeroService } from './../services/hero.service';

    import { GET_HEROES, GET_HEROES_SUCCESS, GET_HEROES_FAIL, GET_HERO, GET_HERO_SUCCESS, GET_HERO_FAIL} from './../actions/hero.action';
    import { CREATE_HERO, CREATE_HERO_SUCCESS, CREATE_HERO_FAIL, DELETE_HERO, DELETE_HERO_SUCCESS, DELETE_HERO_FAIL } from './../actions/hero.action';
    import { UPDATE_HERO, UPDATE_HERO_SUCCESS, UPDATE_HERO_FAIL } from './../actions/hero.action';



    @Injectable()
    export class HeroEffects {
          constructor(private actions$: Actions, private heroService: HeroService) {}

    @Effect() getHeroes$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(GET_HEROES)
    .switchMap( action =>
        this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .map(heroes => ({type: GET_HEROES_SUCCESS, payload: heroes}))
        .catch(() => Observable.of({type: GET_HEROES_FAIL})));

     @Effect() getHero$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(GET_HERO)
    .switchMap( action =>
        this.heroService.getHero(name)
        .map(hero => ({type: GET_HERO_SUCCESS, payload: hero}))
        .catch(() => Observable.of({type: GET_HERO_FAIL})));

    @Effect() createHero$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(CREATE_HERO)
    .switchMap( action =>
        this.heroService.createHero(name)
        .map(hero => ({type: CREATE_HERO_SUCCESS, payload: hero}))
        .catch(() => Observable.of({type: CREATE_HERO_FAIL})));

    @Effect() deleteHero$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(DELETE_HERO)
    .switchMap( action =>
        this.heroService.deleteHero(name)
        .map(hero => ({type: GET_HERO_SUCCESS, payload: hero}))
        .catch(() => Observable.of({type: GET_HERO_FAIL})));
    @Effect() updateHero$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(UPDATE_HERO)
    .switchMap( action =>
        this.heroService.updateHero(name)
        .map(hero => ({type: UPDATE_HERO_SUCCESS, payload: hero}))
        .catch(() => Observable.of({type: UPDATE_HERO_FAIL})));


}

hero-list.reducer.ts

import * as heroes from './../actions/hero.action';
import { Hero } from './../models/hero';


export type HeroListState = Hero[];

const initialState: HeroListState = [];

export function heroListReducer(state = initialState, action: heroes.HeroActions): HeroListState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case heroes.GET_HEROES_SUCCESS:
      return this.action.GET_HEROES_SUCCESS;
    case heroes.CREATE_HERO_SUCCESS:
      return [...state, this.action.CREATE_HERO_SUCCESS];
    case heroes.UPDATE_HERO_SUCCESS:
      return state.map((hero) => {
        if (hero.id === action.payload.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, action.payload);
        }
        return hero;
      });
    case heroes.DELETE_HERO_SUCCESS:
      return state.filter(hero => hero.id !== this.action.DELETE_HERO_SUCCESS);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your reducer

```
switch (action.type) {
    case heroes.GET_HEROES_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload; // this should not be this.action.GET_HEROES_SUCCESS;
```

Also if you are stuck trying to convert Tour of Heros to NGRX v4. Take a look at this [link](http://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/) it has a whole demo for the same .

You can take a look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx).
It has a small demo on ngrx and also more to ngrx 4 links.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have fixed the issue in reducer however heroes still aren't showing up. And I've seen that link before, unfortunately some files seem to be out of date. For instance when I change the hero.action code to the above link example I receive the following error message for payload: "Type '{ type: string; payload: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Action'." @RahulSingh

Comment: @bp3290  updated another link i am not at my desk on phone will check again tomorrow